# SImple HTML DOM parser not parsing <body> tag

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using this simple_html_dom parser to try and parse an external url. I am able to use it correctly on most pages.

However when I try to parse the website
http://talksport.com/football/atletico-madrid-beat-arsenal-and-west-ham-signing-portuguese-wonderkid-diogo-jota

the parser is not recognizing the <body> tag in the html.

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('http://talksport.com/football/atletico-madrid-beat-arsenal-and-west-ham-signing-portuguese-wonderkid-diogo-jota');

// Find any tag for eg. <div>
$tag = $html->find('div',0);
var_dump($tag);
```

I get null as the result.

I tried to figure out why this is happening and found that

```
$x = $html->find('html',0)->children();
```

$x has only one child which is the <head> tag. The <body> tag is not parsed at all.

Anyone come across such an issue before? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use DOMDocument class and cURL, something like this:

```
$url = "http://talksport.com/football/atletico-madrid-beat-arsenal-and-west-ham-signing-portuguese-wonderkid-diogo-jota";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$curlReturn = curl_exec($ch);

$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($curlReturn);
$body = $html->getElementsByTagName("body");

curl_close($ch);
```

It's more powerful than simple parser.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: DOMDocument is giving me a lot of Warnings since the html is not well formed. For eg.
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): End tag : expected '&gt;' in Entity, line: 132

Comment: thanks. figured out how to disable the warnings using libxml_use_internal_errors

Answer (score 3):

The HTML of that web site has many issues. See the [W3 HTML validation report](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Ftalksport.com%2Ffootball%2Fatletico-madrid-beat-arsenal-and-west-ham-signing-portuguese-wonderkid-diogo-jota):

> 16. <kbd>**Error**</kbd> **End tag `div` seen, but there were open elements.**
>     From line 134, column 47; to line 134, column 52
>
>     ```
>     n Live</p></div>?             <
>     ```
> 17. <kbd>**Error**</kbd>: **Unclosed element `a`.**
>     From line 133, column 5; to line 133, column 90
>
>     ```
>     </h2>?                <a href="/live" class="listenLiveButtonTrigger" onclick="listenLive(1);return false;">?
>     ```

... etc.

There is mention of duplicate *id* values, stray closing tags, invalid attributes, use of child style tags, ... and many more issues.

I think Simple HTML DOM parser just gets lost in all that mess.